# open /dev/mem fail even with root and without SELINUX

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-system

Just show my code.

```
root@MSI:/tmp# cat main.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDONLY);
    printf("Result: %d\n", fd);
    if (fd != -1) {
        close(fd);
    } else {
        perror("Failed:");
    }
}
root@MSI:/tmp# gcc main.c 
root@MSI:/tmp# ./a.out 
Result: -1
Failed:: Operation not permitted
```

Root, without SELINUX, `/dev/mem` with `crw-r-----` permission, but open failed.
kernel version `5.4.0-49-generic #53-Ubuntu`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to read a process' virtual memory? If you do, consider using `/proc/<pid>/mem` instead.